# Chunking complex noun phrases in lists with spaCy and generating augmented list

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

So I'm trying to convert an "abbreviated" list of noun phrases describing occupations into a "complete" list of those noun phrases. It should look something like this:

Examples (input --> output):

- General and operations managers --> [general manager, operations manager]
- Bus and truck mechanics and diesel engine specialists --> [bus mechanics, truck mechanics, diesel engine specialists]
- Claims adjusters, appraisers, and examiners --> [claims adjusters, claims appraisers, claims examiners]
- Heavy vehicle and mobile equipment service technicians and mechanics --> [heavy vehicle service technicians, heavy vehicle mechanics, mobile equipment service technicians, mobile equipment mechanics]

I tried a heavy rule-based approach, but it wasn't to my liking.
I also tried simple chunking with spaCy, but the initial results are also not perfect.

The spaCy code looks like this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def get_chunks(sentence):
    res = []

    doc = nlp(u'{}'.format(sentence))

    for np in doc.noun_chunks:
        res.append(np.text)

    return res
```

For the exact inputs as above, the code returns:

- ['operations', 'managers']
- ['Bus and truck mechanics', 'diesel engine specialists']
- ['Claims adjusters', 'appraisers', 'examiners', 'investigators']
- ['Heavy vehicle', 'mobile equipment service technicians', 'mechanics']

I'm considering going to a rule-based approach from here, but maybe someone has a better suggestion?

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Are there multiple forms of this list? Is it only one single long list?

Comment: Most of the forms are very similar to the examples I included. Can be found here: https://www.bls.gov/cps/aa2015/cpsaat11b.pdf

Comment: since you have a single source, you cant use data volume to help really. You can try to use counts of chunks and sort, but most likely you will just have to write code to combine the works correctly